# Junit with Mockito

Tags: unit-testing, mockito

I am testing a Spring impl class with Mockito.

There is a call to a method which returns void.

But the method(`addCruiseMessages`) is returning `NullPointerException` since it has a call to a properties file.

How can I test it successfully?

Impl class:

```
@Path(CruisePricingConstants.SAVE_CRUISE_RESTRICTION)
public Integer saveCruiseRestrictionDetails (List<CruisePricingCruiseDetailsVO> cruiseDetailsVOs){
    List<MessageVO> messageVOs = new ArrayList<MessageVO>();


    MessageVO message = null;

   for(CruisePricingCruiseDetailsVO  cruisePricingCruiseDetailsVO : cruiseDetailsVOs)
   {
       int listLength = cruisePricingCruiseDetailsVO.getViewImpactedCruisesDefinintionVOs().size();
       if(listLength > CruisePricingConstants.ONE)
       {
           Set<CruisePricingViewImpactedCruisesDefinintionVO> set = new HashSet<CruisePricingViewImpactedCruisesDefinintionVO>()  ;
           set.addAll(cruisePricingCruiseDetailsVO.getViewImpactedCruisesDefinintionVOs());
           if(set.size()<listLength)
           {
               message = new MessageVO("msg.searchAndListViewImpactedCruisesWidget.duplicateRecordExist", SproutUtil.getMessage("msg.searchAndListViewImpactedCruisesWidget.invalidCombination"), ErrorSeverity.ERROR);
               messageVOs.add(message);
               WebExceptionUtil.addMessagesToResponse(messageVOs);
               return CruisePricingConstants.ONE;
           }
       }
   }

    LOGGER.debug("CruisePricingViewImpactedCruisesServiceImpl :: saveCruiseRestrictionDetails :: Entry");

    Integer rateID = viewImpactedCruisesComponent.saveCruiseRestrictionDetails(cruiseDetailsVOs);
    if(rateID==CruisePricingConstants.ONE){   
        addCruiseMessages();
        }
    LOGGER.debug("CruisePricingViewImpactedCruisesServiceImpl :: saveCruiseRestrictionDetails :: Exit");
    return rateID;

}
```

Test class.

```
   @Test
   public void saveCruiseRestrictionDetails(){    
          CruisePricingCruiseDetailsVO cruisePricingCruiseDetailsVO = MockFactory.populateCruiseRequestVO();  

          List<CruisePricingCruiseDetailsVO> cruisePricingCruiseDetailsVOs=new ArrayList<CruisePricingCruiseDetailsVO>();
          CruisePricingViewImpactedCruisesDefinintionVO cruisePricingViewImpactedCruisesDefinintionVO=MockFactory.populateImpactedVO();

          List<CruisePricingViewImpactedCruisesDefinintionVO> cruisePricingViewImpactedCruisesDefinintionVOs=new ArrayList<CruisePricingViewImpactedCruisesDefinintionVO>();
          cruisePricingViewImpactedCruisesDefinintionVOs.add(cruisePricingViewImpactedCruisesDefinintionVO);
          cruisePricingCruiseDetailsVO.setViewImpactedCruisesDefinintionVOs(cruisePricingViewImpactedCruisesDefinintionVOs);
          cruisePricingCruiseDetailsVOs.add(cruisePricingCruiseDetailsVO);

            when(cruisePricingViewImpactedCruisesComponent.saveCruiseRestrictionDetails(cruisePricingCruiseDetailsVOs)).thenReturn(1);

          CruisePricingViewImpactedCruisesServiceImpl cimpl=mock(CruisePricingViewImpactedCruisesServiceImpl.class);

          CruisePricingViewImpactedCruisesServiceImpl cp=new CruisePricingViewImpactedCruisesServiceImpl();
          Mockito.stubVoid(cimpl).toReturn().on().addCruiseMessages();

          cruisePricingViewImpactedCruisesServiceImpl.saveCruiseRestrictionDetails(cruisePricingCruiseDetailsVOs);

         assertEquals(new Integer(1),cruisePricingViewImpactedCruisesServiceImpl.saveCruiseRestrictionDetails(cruisePricingCruiseDetailsVOs));



   }`
```

Comment: can you paste the error you are getting

Comment: And paste the code of the method that's throwing the exception?  It's not quite so helpful to have the code of every other method _except_ the one that has the problem.

Comment: Messagevo MVO=new MessageVo

Comment: heres the junit method which is causing the exception:

Comment: Public void getMessage(){
 
messageVOs=new ArrayList<MessageVO>();
               message = new MessageVO("msg.searchAndListViewImpactedCruisesWidget.recordMergedSuccessfully", SproutUtil.getMessage("msg.searchAndListViewImpactedCruisesWidget.recordSavedSuccessfully"), ErrorSeverity.FINE);
             messageVOs.add(message);
             WebExceptionUtil.addMessagesToResponse(messageVOs);
 
}  nullpointer is thrown at sproututil class which gets the message from the properties file.sproututil is a java class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `SproutUtil.getMessage` is the method causing problems, then you have to:

**1)** Extract to a getter method:

```
public String getMessage(String message) {
    return SproutUtil.getMessage(message);
}
```

**2)** Change the implementation so that it calls the getter instead of explicitly calling the static util:

```
message = new MessageVO("msg.searchAndListViewImpactedCruisesWidget.duplicateRecordExist"
,getMessage("msg.searchAndListViewImpactedCruisesWidget.invalidCombination"), ErrorSeverity.ERROR);
```

**3)** Annotate cruisePricingViewImpactedCruisesComponent with Spy (as I believe some methods you want to actually invoke):

```
@Spy
private CruisePricingViewImpactedCruisesComponent cmp;
```

**4)** Mock the getter

```
when(cmp.getMessage(Mockito.any(String.class))).thenReturn("anyString");
```

Try it.